# Is there an equivalent to the mempool concept on Corda?

Tags: blockchain, corda

Im studying some of the core blockchain concepts and stumbled upon mempool, and Im trying to understand what is the equivalent of that on Corda, since there must some form of limitation transaction/flow wise.

Is there a mempool on Corda?
If not,
is there a limit on how many flows can be suspended at once on Corda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Corda doesn't have a mempool; a mempool (in Ethereum) is for unconfirmed (i.e. not included in a block) transactions, since in Corda there is no mining (or blocks); there is no such concept.
- If you're running Corda Open Source (i.e. the free version); your node is limited to one flow thread at a time; if you're running Corda Enterprise, then you can have multiple flow threads running concurrently.
- Flows are suspended when they call `send`, `receive`, `sendAndReceive`, or `sleep`; a checkpoint is created and the stack is written to disk (serialized); when the flow resumes, it deserializes what was written to disk then proceeds execution.
- Before Corda 4.4, if your flow had an external call (i.e. API call, or DB call); the flow thread was locked until that external call was complete (which is a problem for the single threaded Open Source edition). Starting Corda 4.4 you can write asynchronous flow operations which free that thread when the flow is waiting on an operation that takes a long time; you can read about [here](https://blog.b9lab.com/whats-new-and-exciting-in-corda-4-4-6b02c1b7d734).